Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Italian Language Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Quando non si deve mettere l'accento sul pronome "sé"?

Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


Cosa significa "giocare a testa e pila"?

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


"In Belgio" oppure "nel Belgio"?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


What is wrong in the sentence "Servi si nasce, noi lo nacquimo"?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


Qual è la differenza tra "cerchio", "cerchia" e "circolo"?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


Si può usare l'avverbio "possibilmente" nel senso di "è possibile che ..."?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)


"Tradurre in" oppure "tradurre a"?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


What does "idroscalo" mean?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)


"Grazie di" oppure "grazie per"?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)


How do you say "Good job!" in Italian?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

